# npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, when trying to install any package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

Whenever tying to install any type of package I getting this error (errno -4048) operation not permitted. looking for a solution tried to kill any running server but the issue presists. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See if this thread helps: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2663

Comment: Tried all the steps there. it didn't work for me. still getting Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Aviv Avraham\leicht\package.json'.

Comment: This error occurs only when trying to install new packages in this specific folder!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
```

Comment: Hi Yanir, I tried this but still getting the error afterwards when trying to install a package. I t happens only for this specific project, tried  to install packages on another project and it worked